# Mac AppStore Message: {AppName} No longer supported

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

My OSX app is supporting 10.9 and up.
I'm getting emails from users who say that they get the "{My app name} is no longer supported".
I know that they are using 10.9 and above.

Did anyone see it before? Did it happen to anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: Where `{AppName}` is the name of your app or literally that value?

Comment: @trojanfoe the name of my app.

Comment: And is there anything unusual about the app (by unusual I mean not written in Objective-C targeting x86_64)?

Comment: No there is not anything unusual.

Comment: Anything in the console log about the reason?

Comment: do they get the error when launching the app or when loading from MAS?

Comment: When launching the app after installing.